# Length=4 in asp.net mvc query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, redirect

I am developing an asp.net mvc application. When i pass parameter to my form as mentioned below, I get Length=4 in URl(i.e. query string). My `Request.QueryString["returnUrl"]` in `null` and `Request.QueryString` shows Length=4. This is creating problem for my redirection. Please help.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "User", new AjaxOptions { }, new { id = "formLogin" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Comment: Your not using the correct overload of `Ajax.BeginForm()`. I suspect you want [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470626(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : When I open and close the brackets, I dont get any overload that you mentioned in the link. There is not this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,

Comment: `@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "User", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },  new AjaxOptions { }, new { id = "formLogin" }))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : where do i set the return url in the viewbag.?

Comment: In the controller method that generates the view - I have given you an example of how to use the correct overload to generate route parameters but have no idea why you would use `Ajax.BeginForm()` for this

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Not working.. as I dont know from where ReturnUrl is coming.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : so instead of ajax.begin form, what can be used?

Comment: If you don't, how would I :) What you doing makes no sense - ajax methods stay on the same page so what is the point of the `ReturnUrl` route parameter?